Windows 11: The Settings app opens in a very tiny window
Grettings,
Every time I open the settings app in Windows 11 it opens in a very annoying and tiny window and the same place.
OS Build: 22631.4460
I have tried:

Resizing + Ctrl + Closing the window, several times
Resetting registry by cmd line
Resetting registry by downloading a .reg file on the web.
Downloaded the app WinSize2 but didnt know how to install
Downloaded the app Shellfolderfix but didnt know how to use it.

This is how it looks:


Have you tried running Reset-AppxPackage? All you need is the package name.
